# Primefaces slected row id == null

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a working datatable that can list out restaurant objects.
I want to delete/edite the selected ones but when I select one the following exception shows up:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The given id must not be null!
```

Here is the table:

```
    <h:form id="restaurantForm">
    <p:dataTable var="restaurant"
            value="#{restaurantLazyBean.lazyDataModel}" paginator="true"
            rows="10" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,50" id="carTable" lazy="true"
            selectionMode="single" selection="#{RestaurantEditBean.selected}"
            rowKey="#{restaurant.id}"
            paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}">
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                listener="#{RestaurantEditBean.onRowSelect()}"/>

            <p:column headerText="ID">
                <h:outputText value="#{restaurant.id}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

    </h:form>
```

Now all ids appear in the table but on selection the exception shows up.
I tried to do everything according to the primefaces example. But they didn't even have the rowKey attribute.

Heres the bean if thats relevant.

```
@Named("RestaurantEditBean")
@ViewScoped
@EJB(name = "ejb.RestaurantService", beanInterface = RestaurantService.class)
public class RestaurantEditBean {
@EJB
private RestaurantService restaurantService;
private RestaurantDTO selected;

public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    selected = ((RestaurantDTO) event.getObject());
}

public RestaurantService getRestaurantService() {
    return restaurantService;
}

public void setRestaurantService(RestaurantService restaurantService) {
    this.restaurantService = restaurantService;
}

public RestaurantDTO getSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(RestaurantDTO selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
```

}

Primefaces: 5.3
JSF: 2.2

Comment: did you debug RestaurantEditBean.selected method? also does your bean name camelCase?

Comment: @HRgiger RestaurantEditBean.selected is that a method? I thought that was a field. According to the http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml
that property should be an object with the same type of the list.
@Named("RestaurantEditBean") it looks like this.

Comment: yes but it calls setSelected to assign field value because your field is encapsulated. Also your bean name looks ok, just add a break point to this.selected = selected; and check parameter in debug mode.

Comment: The flow doesn't even reach that part of the code. Heres a screenshot of the network. [link](http://s3.postimg.org/qnr3e0zap/dontgetit.png)

Comment: Why is the annotation `@EJB` positioning over the managed bean `RestaurantEditBean`? What magic is being played by it? How is the exception coming from `org.springframework` while using EJBs?

Comment: spring data jpa I gues, see my answer. I know i'm noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I did a terrible mistake.
In my LazyDataModel I had to override a function.

```
@Override
    public RestaurantDTO getRowData(String rowKey) {
        Long id = Long.parseLong(rowKey);
        return restaurantService.findById(id);
        }
```

The issue was cause by the previous `Long.getLong(rowKey)` and that one returned null.